is it possible to get confusion matrix if I know the precision,recall,mAP of a model?
is it possible to get confusion matrix if I know the precision,recall,mAP of a model?
i want to know the number of false negatives and false positives from my precision,recall,mAP of the model.
i have created a object detection model.
